# Visibility of the root of an inflated layout is changing with the child's visibility

Tags: android, visibility, layout-inflater

I have an odd error/side effect happening with my Android app I am doing right now for a school project. 
The end goal is supposed to be a view that gets revealed after pressing a button at the top of the screen. It is initially placed invisibly and toggled after that.

However, for some reason the root view it gets attached to is also having its visibility toggled, which so happens to be the main layout of the fragment it is in. So effectively, the initial setVisibility() call is causing my entire fragment to disappear.

Any reason why?

EDIT: Giving the layout a FrameLayout to be attached to fixes the problem. However, the question still remains: what is causing this behaviour?

Code:

```
        @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //prep timeselector view for transitions
        dashboardContainer = this.getView().findViewById(R.id.dashboardContainer);
        vgTimeSelector = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.viewgroup_timeselector,dashboardContainer);
        vgTimeSelector.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //add timeselector popup
        bellButton = this.getView().findViewById(R.id.notificationButton);
        bellButton.setOnClickListener(togglerListener);
    }

private void toggleTimeSwitcherView () {

        //this is all animation stuff for timeselector
        int x = vgTimeSelector.getRight();
        int y = vgTimeSelector.getTop();
        int endRadius = (int) Math.hypot(vgTimeSelector.getWidth(),vgTimeSelector.getHeight());

        if (vgTimeSelector.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            vgTimeSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(vgTimeSelector, x, y, 0, endRadius);
            animator.start();
        }
        else {
            Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(vgTimeSelector, x, y, endRadius, 0);
            animator.start();
            vgTimeSelector.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

XML:

```xml
Fragment Layout:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardFragment"
    android:id="@+id/dashboardContainer">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/notificationButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Bell"/> 

...

</RelativeLayout>

Child View:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:id="@+id/timeselector"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Notify me later"
        android:id="@+id/notifyTV"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/notifyTV">

        <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="N"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Y"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling the visibility of the entire `dashboardContainer`.
I believe this `dashboardContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
should be replaced with `vgTimeSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and

`dashboardContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` with `vgTimeSelector.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

```
//this is all animation stuff for timeselector
        int x = vgTimeSelector.getRight();
        int y = vgTimeSelector.getTop();
        int endRadius = (int) Math.hypot(vgTimeSelector.getWidth(),vgTimeSelector.getHeight());

        if (vgTimeSelector.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            dashboardContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(vgTimeSelector, x, y, 0, endRadius);
            animator.start();
        }
        else {
            Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(vgTimeSelector, x, y, endRadius, 0);
            animator.start();
            dashboardContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Well that was *a* issue, it wasn't *the* issue. Even after changing that the problem still remains. 
However putting it in a FrameLayout does fix the issue, it doesn't explain this behaviour